# Video is appearing at the top of the screen. How can I align it to center

Tags: react-native

I have a video player in react native which is at the top of the page but I want it to be in the center of the screen How can I achieve it. Here is the code

```
      return (
      <View>
        <KSYVideo
         source={{
         uri: "rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4"

         }} // Can be a URL or a local file.
      ref={ref => {
        this.player = ref;
      }} // Store reference
      volume={1.0}
      muted={false}
      paused={this.state.paused} // Pauses playback entirely.
      resizeMode="stretch" // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.*
      repeat={true} // Repeat forever.
      playInBackground={false}  
      progressUpdateInterval={250.0}
      style={{ height: 300, justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center' }}
    />
```

Comment: Try to give `justifyContent: 'center'` to parent view.

Comment: Parent view means?

Comment: I have already set in the styles section

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}} >
    <KSYVideo
     source={{
     uri: "rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4"

     }} // Can be a URL or a local file.
  ref={ref => {
    this.player = ref;
  }} // Store reference
  volume={1.0}
  muted={false}
  paused={this.state.paused} // Pauses playback entirely.
  resizeMode="stretch" // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.*
  repeat={true} // Repeat forever.
  playInBackground={false}  
  progressUpdateInterval={250.0}
  style={{ height: 300, 
  alignSelf: 'center' }}
/>
</View>
```